# How do I tell Texmaker where to look for packages

Tags: texlive, texmaker, paths

I recently  installed texlive from the internet (using tar found [here](https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html)).
When the installation finished, I added the following lines to `/etc/bash.bashrc`:

```
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/i386-linux:$PATH; export PATH
MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH; export MANPATH
INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/doc/info:$INFOPATH; export INFOPATH
```

The same three lines I added to `~/.profile` and to `~/.bashrc`

Also I added this line to the manpath file (`/etc/manpath.config`):

```
MANPATH_MAP /usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/i386-linux  /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/doc/man
```

I'm not really sure what it means to add those lines to those files, but it doesn't seem to change anything if I leave them there or if I cut them off.

Now, when I try to compile something on Texmaker, I get an error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `package_name.sty' not found.
```

That comes from the file

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/package_name/package_name.sty
```

So as I can see, Texmaker is looking for the packages on the path:

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex
```

but all the packages installed by texlive are on the path:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex
```

The first path, I think, came up when I installed (from Software Manager) the packages `texlive-latex-base` and `texlive-latex-extra`.
Now that I have the actual texlive, I removed those packages and manually remove the directories they created (So now `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex` doesn't even exist!)

I tried removing and reinstalling Texmaker (after I deleted the previous directory), and same thing with TexLive (I installed TexLive first and then Texmaker), but nothing changed.

Now, all I need to do is tell Texmaker where all the packages are, but I guess that's what adding those lines to the mentioned files is all about.

So, I don't know. Did I do something wrong? Is there any other way to manually tell Texmaker where to find the packages?

Thank you for reading this, I appreciate your time.

I use Linux Mint 15 Olivia.

Comment: First, as a sanity check, can you compile the document from the command line? That is, forget TeXmaker for a minute and just check that TeX Live really is installed correctly. If that fails, check the output of `echo $PATH`. If it succeeds, then you can return to the issue in TeXmaker. Also, please tell us which GNU/Linux distro you are using. [How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092) may be helpful (especially if you use Debian/Ubuntu but even if you don't.)

Comment: Assuming from the package names that you're on Debian or Ubuntu, I'm going to bet you still have `texlive-base` or other distribution-provided TeX packages installed, and those are what you're running. Running `which pdflatex` and `dpkg -l | grep texlive` will tell for certain.

Comment: @cfr I can compile from the command line. But now I can't compile the same document from Texmaker. I don't think that's normal.  
I'll read the docummentation and see if that helps.

Comment: @MikeRenfro `which pdflatex` gives `/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/i386-linux/pdflatex`, which Ok. `dpkg -l | grep texlive` gives no output at all

Comment: By the way, you ought not set MANPATH at all (probably). Doing so is deprecated on most distributions. How did you install TeXmaker?

Comment: Assuming you are using Debian or Ubuntu, try `sudo ln -s /usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/* /opt/texbin` (from [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/39222)}.

Comment: Next option, do a `which -a pdflatex` to see if there's a second executable floating around. There's also a chance that TeXmaker isn't using your default path, and maybe a logout/login or reboot cycle would fix that. And you can check [TeXmaker's preferences](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/doc.html#SECTION02) to make sure there are no hard-coded paths in there.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem: I could compile from the terminal but not from Texmaker. Turns out the solution is fairly simple.

Open up a terminal and run

```
which pdflatex
```

On my machine I get the output as

```
/usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux/
```

Then, open the Texmaker configuration Window from the Options menu. In the Commands tab replace whatever is in quotes in the PdfLaTeX textbox with the above path. You should be good to go from here.

Comment: I get something using `which`. I changed the path in the configuration. But it still doesn't find standard packages. I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: Ah, this wouldn't work on Windows. I guess there you need to find where the pdflatex executable is. But I'm not sure since I don't use Windows.